# Java, Identificar teclado que dispara el evento

Tags: java, java-swing, eventos

tengo dos teclados usb conectados a un pc, al pulsar cualquier tecla me gustaría saber que teclado de los dos ha sido.

He buscado por la clase keyevent algun metodo que me devuelva un id o algo especifico de cada teclado pero no he encontrado nada.

Comment: No, no lo hay. De hecho incluso en lenguajes de más bajo nivel es complicado obtener esa información porque necesitas acceder al API nativa del sistema operativo. Piensa que Java se ejecuta en un *sandbox* (la JVM) que precisamente está para abstraerte del hardware, por lo que necesitarías ejecutar código nativo en un proceso aparte para poder obtener la información. Por ejemplo, pasa algo similar incluso en C#, a menos que ignores el API estándar de .Net y accedas al API Raw de Windows: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard

Comment: Gracias. Al final cambie a unos lectores de barras usb-com de esta forma ademas de no tener que escribir puedo identificar el dispositivo por el puerto com. Gracias de nuevo